# Seperate each scan line from pointcloud data

Tags: point-clouds, lidar

[image]

I have many frames of pointcloud data and would like to separate each scan line to do further processing on it. Any fast ways to get each scan lines from the pointcloud data.

Comment: Please provide data format of pointcloud you are operating on. If one scan is one dimensional vector you can presume that every layer has the same amount of points, but I'm not sure that they are putted in correct order neither horizontally nor vertically.

Comment: It is a pointcloud2 Ros sensor message. Which contains x, y, z and intensity for each point in the pointcloud. I have a very poor solution implemented for the moment by finding relative distance between points. I could share a rosbag of the some sensor data frames to help clarify the data structure.

Comment: Basically this is the only way you can do it. You just iterate through the array of all geometry_msgs/Point32[] points and sort if the way you need. The problem is that this array is unsorted when you receive it and contains no correspondence between points and lines/layers.